# ¿Se puede mostrar una ventana oculta que se inicializa en el main.js ante request del servidor Express?

Tags: nodejs, express, electron

Quiero hacer una aplicación de Electron con un servidor Express que antes de una solicitud muestre la ventana principal, esto es posible, soy un principiante, no tengo mucha idea. Aprecio la ayuda de todos, dejo el ejemple del main.js y el server.js para ver si me pueden dar una mano

**main.js**

```
//main.js
const isDev = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development');

let installExtension = null;
if ( isDev ) {
  installExtension = require('electron-devtools-installer');
}

const electron = require('electron');
const MainWindow  = require('./windows/mainWindow.js');
const {app, ipcMain} = electron;
let main = null;


app.on('ready', function () {
    if ( isDev ) installExtentions();
    main = new MainWindow();
})

ipcMain.on('quit-app', function() {
    main.window.close();
    app.quit();
});

ipcMain.on('show-main-window-event', function() {
    main.window.show();
    app.dock.show();
});

ipcMain.on('show-about-window-event', function() {
    about.window.show();
});

const installExtentions = function () {
    installExtension['default']( installExtension['REDUX_DEVTOOLS'] )
    installExtension['default']( installExtension['REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS'] )
}
```

**server.js**

Quiero realizar la llamada a la función que está en main.js ipcMain.emit ('show-main-window-event'), no puedo lograrlo.

```
//server.js
var app, express, bodyParser; 
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
express = require('express');

app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/locations', function(req, res) {

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
var val1, val2;

val1 = req.body.val1;
val2 = req.body.val2;

if ( val1 == '201518744787')
    ipcMain.emit('show-main-window-event') //<-- Call function into main.js


var response = {
    status  : 200,
    success : 'ok'
}

    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));

});

app.listen(8999);
```

**mainWindow.js**

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path');
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');


class MainWindow {
  constructor() {

    let htmlPath = 'file://' + path.join(__dirname, '..') + '/index.html'
    const { width, height } = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
        this.window = new BrowserWindow({
            show: false,
            width: 300, 
            height: 500, 
            x: width-300, 
            y: height-500,
            backgroundColor: "#045FB4",
            minimizable: false,
            maximizable: false,
            frame: false
        })
    this.window.loadURL(htmlPath);
    this.window.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
    }
}

module.exports = MainWindow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probá con_

```
ipcRenderer.sendSync('show-main-window-event'','');
```

Y te faltó:

```
this.window.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    this.window.show()
});
```